# MySQL STR_TO_DATE returns NULL when using week number directive (%U, %u, %V or %v)

Tags: mysql, date-format, str-to-date

`NULL` is being returned from `STR_TO_DATE` function when using the week number format directive (`%U`, `%u`, `%V` or `%v`) on `MySQL 8.0.35`. The [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) indicates that `STR_TO_DATE` should be the inverse of `DATE_FORMAT`. I expected to get the same/similar date returned back that was provided as input to `DATE_FORMAT` function.

[Here](https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=645df8c4-8aeb-4fe6-b8e1-1a7dd5cbf66c) I've prepared a sqlfiddle, or you can use the following source code to recreate issue:

```sql
SET @_NOW=NOW(6), @_FMT='%YW%U';
SELECT
  @_NOW,@_FMT,
  DATE_FORMAT(@_NOW,@_FMT) AS `formatted`,
  STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(@_NOW,@_FMT),@_FMT) AS `parsed`;
```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Misprint. Must be `@_FMT='%Y%W%U'`

Comment: @Akina, @easleyfixed - I am deliberately producing a formatted date like: `2024W05`.  Not `2024Tuesday04`.

Comment: I'd say this is by design: Since a "date" can't be derived from a year and a week the systme is setting the day portion to null which sets all values to null.. "The STR_TO_DATE() sets all incomplete date values, which are not provided by the input string, to NULL. " From https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date-functions/mysql-str_to_date/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that converting to a week doesn't convert to a specific day, but MySQL data validation must validate the year, month, and day.

The following works, because it maps to a specific day (the first day of the week):

```
mysql> select str_to_date('2024W04 Sunday', '%XW%V %W') as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2024-01-28 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I guess I was hoping that it would respect the "first day of the week" as a default if left ambiguous.

Comment: Some other user may prefer that "last day of the week" is the default. Given that neither is a clear winner as the best default, it's best to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design:
Since a "day portion of the date" can not be derived from a year and a week the system is setting the day portion to null which sets all values in the date to null.

Put another way, you can't do this. The date value is incomplete and thus returns null. So while str_to_Date is the in general the opposite of date_format, str_To_Date can only process date formats which can be resolved to a specific Year, month, and Day (which must be a valid date) So not all formats can be "bi-directionally" converted.

**Per: http://mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date-functions/mysql-str_to_date**

The STR_TO_DATE() sets all incomplete date values, which are not provided by the input string, to NULL."

**Per: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date**

If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str cannot be parsed according to the rules followed by the server, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.

Demo wtih Warnings enabled:
https://dbfiddle.uk/ac6H2HIx

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
SET @_NOW=NOW(6), @_FMT='%YW%U';
SELECT
  @_NOW,@_FMT,
  DATE_FORMAT(@_NOW,@_FMT) AS `formatted`,
  STR_TO_DATE('2024W04',@_FMT) AS `parsed`;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Returns:

```
Warning 1411    Incorrect datetime value: '2024W04' for function str_to_date
```

This seems to support the theory since a valid "day" can not be derrived, the whole value is set to null.  Why?  the system doesn't know what "Day" of the date to put in; so no day is.  The system then can't verifiy it to be a valide date; and thus returns null and throws a warning.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize warnings were being thrown and that would have saved me some time.